# How to fix Metadata Failed to load system privileges from Connection. java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist-error

Tags: database, oracle, ide

I set up an Oracle database and successfully established a connection in Intellj 2019.1. I can create tables, start queries and so on.

I want to use the DB Navigator of Intellj to see my views, triggers, procedures etc.

In oracle-sqlplus i created a user account as follows:

```
create user me identified by 1234;
grant create session to me;
grant create table to me;
grant unlimited tablespace to me;
```

In Intellj the **SQL-Dialect** is set to "Oracle".

When I now open the DB Navigator, no triggers, views, etc. are displayed. Therefore I updated "System privileges"

[image]

and get the following error message

[image]

**DB Navigator - Metadata
            Failed to load system privileges from Connection. Feature not supported: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, whether it's Intellj himself, or whether I might have missed something?

Comment: Are you able to see tables?

Comment: Yeah, can see them and can work with the database as normal. The error message is only displayed if I want to view the triggers and views in the DB browser. Schemas and users are also shown in the DB Browser strangely.

Comment: Execute the following command from the sys and check if you are able to see the triggers: `grant resource to me;`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work

Comment: **Fixed the Problem** by deleting the existing User. I created a new User and i have used the following commands to specify the user: GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA to me;